# html links to files in my domain

Tags: html, hyperlink

I need to link to files in my domain.  I don't want to use the full https://my-domain.com/dir-1/file.gif

Assuming the file isn't in a subdirectory under my current page but is in another subdirectory off somewhere.  How do I link to it with minimal coding?

There's a lot of info on the web about html links but usually after one basic example they diverge off into coding colored links or css.

This may also be an irrelevant question but is there any way I can have a unique page identifier and link to that page even if it's location or name changes?  I do not want to use another #$%^&?! CMS system.

Answer (score 0):

Say your index file is in the root directory, and you want to link to that gif in your `dir-1` directory, you'd need to use `dir-/file.gif` as your url.

If as an image:

`<img src="dir-1/file.gif" />`

Comment: thanks but the files are not in the home directory.  I did find one work around which is to use ../../../  for example to go up 3 directories, then I can go back down.    One a simplar question posted before one user said I could do a global variable declaration of the url of my website somewhere and then just reference that.

Comment: That will work, `../` is a command to go up one directory. Thats probably your best bet as you need a absolute path if you're not using a CMS

Comment: I didn't want to use 'code'"http://my-site.com"'code'  as I just got an SSL certif so now I'm "https://my-site.com"[\code]  For some reason this editor hides my text so it appears differently